# extendable mremap on anonymously mmaped memory

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, mmap

I was believing mremap would have a realloc-like behavior until debugging things like the following lines of code in C.

```
#define PAGESIZE 0x1000
void *p = mmap(0, PAGESIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED, -1, 0);
void *p2 = mremap(p, PAGESIZE, PAGESIZE * 2, MREMAP_MAYMOVE);
// then any future access to the 2nd page in p2 would generate a nice SIGBUS
```

After viewing several old threads in some mailing-lists I know mmap was originally designed for 'pure' file mapping and folks who designed mremap seem not caring about codes like that above.

I know a shared memory object would do for this. But shm_open/shm_unlink require filenames and I don't want to deal with strings in this very project. And, I am not sure, maybe shared memory objects would more or less reduce performance of my application.

I'm just wondering if it's possible to make mremap work fine(fine here means no SIGBUS when expanding) with anonymously mapped memory, or if there is some similar methods simple&fast?

thx to all in advance :-)

Comment: Could you not just create a second mapping immediately following the first, using `mmap` with `MAP_FIXED`?

Comment: to caf: there might be MANY such calls(actually what I'm implementing is a memory management toolkit like malloc/free/realloc in glibc), so after some mapping there may not be enough virtual address space for expanding :-(